# Ignore SSL with rest client and androidannotations

Tags: android, rest, ssl, rest-client, android-annotations

I'm trying to consume a rest api with client and androidannotations. It works perfectly, but when I do an api with an invalid certificate returned me an error.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I have found several solutions (like [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https?answertab=votes#tab-top)) to ignore this validation (only in development, production have the correct certificate), but none have managed to combine it with rest and androidannotations client.

Does anyone know how to do?

Comment: Have you tried the REST error handler?

Answer (score 0):

Make your annotated service interface implement RestClientSupport like so:

```
@Rest
public interface MyService extends RestClientSupport
```

Then you can call

```
RestTemplate t = service.getRestTemplate();
```

And follow these instructions:

http://www.jroller.com/jurberg/entry/using_a_hostnameverifier_with_spring